# Trick to determining whether random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let's say if we are dealing with a joint PDF where the support has an inequality that depends on both $x$ and $y$, such as the example below:

Suppose we have the random variables $X$ and $Y$ with the joint probability density function given by:

$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
      14x^2y & 0\leq x\leq 1 \text{ and } 0 \leq y \leq x^2 \\
      0 &\text{else}
\end{cases}
$

Then, can we look at the support to note that $0 \leq y \leq x^2$ and use it as a hint to find out whether $X$ and $Y$ are independent/dependent since it appears that $y$ always depends on $x^2$?

Comment: This is similar to realizing that two disjoint events are almost never independent! If you know one happened - you can rule out the other completely!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is a very good intuitive way to think of it.  Based on that, you should strongly suspect $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.  To verify this rigorously, you would need to find some subsets $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $P(X \in A, Y \in B) \ne P(X \in A) P(Y \in B)$.  Here, I would recommend looking at something like $P(X \le \frac 12, Y > \frac 14)$ and comparing it with $P(X \le \frac 12)P(Y > \frac 14)$.